# Customize the auto-generated name of an embedded primary key

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to customize the name automatically generated by the APP/Hibernate on an embeddedId but all my attempts have failed.

Is there any way to do it?

EDIT : I add a code sample for a better understanding.

I have an embeddedId in my entity class. This EmbeddedID is compose with 3 fields.

```
@EmbeddedId
private StockEmbeddedId stockEmbeddedId;
```

When hibernate create my table structure and the primary key associate to this embeddedId, it give a name like "PK_mytable_fu_23423432424". It's this name i want to customize

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood, you could use @AttributeOverride annotation on customized property:

```java
@AttributeOverride(
   name = "id",
   column = @Column(name = "CUSTOM_ID")
)
```

Comment: Thanks Anthony for your reply but @AttributeOverride allows to override the generate name of a column in an embedded id.
I want to override the generated name of the resulting primary key

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation i think it's totally impossible to customize the name :'(